# download documents from online service

Tags: .net, session, download

I'm trying to download a lot of documents from an online service, first I need to login to a web site using username and password, then click on specific folder link, there will be documents listed, if I right click on one of the document "save the document", I can save the document to local, I'm wondering if can do this process automatically.

If I check the download link, it's just showing /Services/MessageRetriever.ashx,  no any other ID embedded in the URL,  I believe each document has it's own session.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Does the online service offer an API?  If it does, then it shouldn't be too difficult to create a client that does what you want (provided the API has that functionality)

Comment: No API provide for the download, at least not open to public

Answer (score 0):

If the web page is using session variables there's not a lot that you can do but you might find that the ID or other information is being sent in the request body instead of the URL.
You can check this by using tools such as Fiddler to inspect the HTTP request and response.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the tips, I was able to use Apache HTTPclient to do the login, then start download the document, however after about 20 minutes, it will get error failed to download the documents any more, looks like it hit the IIS session timeout; it's weird, I'm keep calling the /Services/MessageRetriever.ashx, it should NOT have timeout error, what could cause the error?   I have to disconnect and re-login again to continue the download,  it's not ideal, is there a better way to keep the session alive?